# grant new user write permission for EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

i added a new user "developer" to my EC2 so that he can access my /var/www/html via ftp. but when "developer" tried uploading files to the directory, he's not allowed. how do i grant this user write permission?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your user to the group www-data and set 775 permissions in the folder.